# Shell script to ping hosts pc won't work

Tags: bash, ping

I'm trying to make a script to ping in a certain network. But if I try it with for example `./pingtest.sh 63 66`, I get the error `ping: unknown host 192.168.129.`.
This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function pingTest(){    
    ping 192.168.129.$1

}

function helpText(){
    echo Please give in some numbers.
}
until [ -z $1 ]
do

case $1 in
    [0-9]*) pingTest;;
    [a-z]*) echo Error, please give in numbers;shift;;  
    -h ) helpText;;
    -help ) helpText;;
esac  
shift
done
```

Can someone help me to make this work?

I'm also trying to give how many of the pinged addresses are up, any ideas how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `$1` to the function

```
case $1 in
    [0-9]*) pingTest "$1";;
    [a-z]*) echo Error, please give in numbers;shift;;
```

**Additional Question**

`ping` will return an error if a specified number of packets don't return in a certain time limit. The number of packets can be specified with the `-c` flag and the timeout with the `-w` flag, these both take a number for number of packets and number of seconds respectively.

If you are wanting a clean looking output you can pipe a commands output to `/dev/null`.

These can be combined to update your script to look something like this...

```
#!/bin/bash

function pingTest(){
    # If after 5 seconds 4 packets haven't been received then return 1
    # else return 0
    # This also pipes to output from ping to /dev/null
    ping -c 4 -w 5 "192.168.129.$1" > /dev/null 2>&1 && return 0 || return 1
}

function helpText(){
    # Quoting is important.
    # It makes it nicer and safer.
    echo "Please give in some numbers."
}

alive_ips=0

until [ -z $1 ]
do
    case $1 in
        # You have all the space you want. Use it :) Space out them lines.
        [0-9]*)
            # If the function return 0 then increment the alive ips
            # If not then don't
            if pingTest "$1"
            then
                echo "$1 is alive"
                # Increment number of alive ip addresses
                (( alive_ips++ ))
            else
                echo "$1 is down"
            fi
        ;;
        [a-z]*)
            echo "Error, please give in numbers"
            # shift
            # No need for a shift here
        ;;
        "-help" | "-h" )
            #You can combine these flags
            helpText
            # Get the script to exit after you ask for help
            exit 0
        ;;
    esac  
    shift
done

echo ""
echo "The number of alive ips are: $alive_ips"

exit 0
```

**Additional Additional Question :)**

*How to allow ranges to be entered and for them to be expanded?*

This is getting a bit more complex this little program but it should be that hard to implement.

An additional case statement will be needed and this will need to be inserted above the `[0-9]*)` as we don't want it to match that one but to only match parameters with a `-` in them.

The new case will look like this...

```
*"-"* )
    # Take the input and replace all '-' characters with ' '
    # And put them into an array ( )
    range=( ${1//-/ } )

    # Check that there is only 2 items.
    if (( ${#range[@]} != 2 ))
    then
        echo "Too many arguments in $1"
        # Shift the arguments to the next one
        shift
        # Move onto next argument and stop executing any more
        # code in this case
        continue
    fi

    # Use the seq command to produce a list at integers between the two
    # ip addresses and put them into an array
    ip_range=( $(seq ${range[@]}) )

    # Set all the $1, $2, $3 ... to What they are now ($@) followed by the
    # expanded range (${ip_range[@]})
    set -- $@ ${ip_range[@]}

;;
```

Comment: I'm also trying to give how many of the pinged addresses are up, any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: @Gregory I've updated my answer to show you how to do this :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I just have one last question. How do i get that if I type ./pingtest.sh 41-46 it will ping 6 adresses with 41 till 46 as the last digit?

Comment: @Gregory You would want to use the case (switch) to check for a parameter with `"-"` in it, so you know that it is a `41-46` parameter. You will then evaluate that parameter to get the two numbers out and use something like `seq` to get an array of numbers to use. You can then do `set -- $@ ${array_of_numbers[@]}` which will put those numbers to the end of your passed in arguments list.

Comment: So in my case i would set `"-" )` ? But what would the code then be? I'm not so good with arrays :/

Comment: It would be `*"-"* )` as it can have anything around it. The you would `range=( ${1//-/ } )` to make an array out of the parameter but remove the dashes and replace them with a space **Note the space in the `${}`**. Then you would do `ip_range=( $(seq ${range[@]}) )` to make and array of all the ip addresses _you might want to check the array size prior to make use it is of size 2 and only contains numbers_. Then you would call the `set -- $@ ${ip_range[@]}`.

Comment: Is there maybe another way to get the result? This seems a little bit difficult to me :/

Comment: There is probably multiple ways but this is the way I'm seeing at the moment as it would fit in your code nicely. It's only 4 lines, maybe 6/7 with error checking. to be fare it does have some more complex stuff. Give me a minute and I'll append it to my answer and explain it better up there :)

Comment: @Gregory Bam! Done! Answer has been updated. It should work. Not got a linux PC atm to test it on :P

Comment: I have another question. When i give in `./pingtest.sh -sum 63 66` i want ping and list a summary at the end that says "pc's up: ... pc's down: ....". So i have to put in my case `-sum )`, but how do I say that he only does the echo at the end?

Comment: @Filip You would want the `-sum` case to toggle a variable e.g. `print_sum_bool=1`. Then in your `[0-9]*`  case you can add alive and dead ip's to two arrays from within the if...else... statements `alive_ip+=( "$1" )` `dead_ip=( "$1" )`. Then after the `until` loop you would check the bool `(( print_sum_bool == 1 ))` and if it is true then print out the alive and dead ip's `echo "Alive ip addresses: ${alive_ip[*]}"` `"Dead ip addresses: ${dead_ip[*]}"`

Answer (score 0):

Functions have their own parameter list, taken from the parameters passed into them.,  They can't see the main script's parameter list.  As you're not passing the value into pingTest, it's evaluating as the empty string.  Call ping test with

```
pingTest "$1";;
```

Comment: I'm also trying to give how many of the pinged addresses are up, any ideas how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

1. Replace `[0-9]*) pingTest;;` with `[0-9]*) pingTest "$1";;` to not call `pingTest` without arguments
2. `ping`, when called the way you do, will run forever. You'll want to use `ping -c 4` or so to send a limited number of packets.
3. It would be a really good idea to quote `$1` everywhere you use it, in case someone passes you an argument with spaces in it. That is to say, replace `$1` with `"$1"` everywhere. This is good practice with all variables.

Comment: I'm also trying to give how many of the pinged addresses are up, any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: `ping` returns 0 (which means true to the shell) if the host is reachable and non-zero otherwise, so you're looking for something like `i=0; for ip in "$@"; do if ping -c4 "192.168.129.$ip"; then i=$((i + 1)); fi; done; echo $i`. It seems like a sane idea to shut `ping` up with `ping -c4 "192.168.129.$ip" > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: where should i place it? inside my until loop but outside the case?

Comment: That would be a replacement for the loop. If you want to integrate it into your loop, the important part is between `if` and `fi`.

Comment: don't I need the until loop?

Comment: There are many ways to skin this cat. An `until` loop is one way to wade through all arguments, `for ip in "$@"` is another. Use whichever you like better. What I was getting at was the `if ping -c 4 host; then i=$((i + 1)); fi` bit that increases `i` by one each time a host was available. If you do that in a loop, by the end `i` will be the number of hosts that were available.